# How to get APIViews and ViewSets to show on API Root when using Router with Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I recently started using DRF and am wondering how to get the automatically generated API Root provided by a Router to display endpoint routes that don't come from ViewSet-based views.

In my case, I have some non-ViewSet (generic) class-based views (ListAPIView and RetrieveAPIView) in my views.py that I would like to appear in my API Root.

I am open to alternative solutions to this, e.g. should I abandon ViewSets and implement those endpoints differently, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to follow the [approach in Tutorial 5](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis#creating-an-endpoint-for-the-root-of-our-api) and define an explicit root endpoint with the `api_view` decorator?

Comment: found another question that helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389248/how-can-i-register-a-single-view-not-a-viewset-on-my-router?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way here is to:

- keep using all your preferred ViewSets / Generic* / Mixins / bare views. This is where the real work happens.
- rewrite the `APIRoot`-View (it is not that complex, see [the source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L245)).
- either use the urlconfig or extend the `DefaultRouter` to make DRF use your APIRoot-View.