# Error while initializing rest framework urls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm refactoring my REST API now. After using `router` instead of direct urls I can't launch my project. Where am I wrong?

**Error:**

```
TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Device(models.Model):
    ...

class Measure(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    ...

class PeriodAverage(models.Model):
    measure = models.ForeignKey(Measure)
```

**urls.py:**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'devices', views.DevicesList)
router.register(r'devices/{pk}/measures', views.MeasuresList, 'Measure')
router.register(r'measures/{pk}/averages', views.PeriodAveragesList, 'Average')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
class DevicesList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DeviceSerializer


class MeasuresList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.MeasureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...


class PeriodAveragesList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PeriodAverageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers work with `ViewSet`s. Your `PeriodAveragesList` extends `ListAPIView`, which is a class based view, not a `ViewSet`.

If you still want to use a router for that view, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441337/2011147) for a workaround.